# Log4j file name

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

I wanted to have the log file name in this format:

> function_YYYYMMDDH24MI-record.log

This is my log4j.xml configuration. Is there a way to name the log file this name

```
 <appender name="function" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/function-" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMddHHmm" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">       
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t]-[%C:%M()] %m%n" />
      </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Generally, the current log file does not contain dates, but it gets one when it is rolled. If it is also the same for your case, how would the current file be named without the date?

Comment: My Answer is below, it works as I need


       <appender name="function" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/function-" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'_'yyyyMMddHHmm'-record'" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">       
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t]-[%C:%M()] %m%n" />
      </layout>
</appender>